# User login can'd identify user position

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

User register as student or tutor during registration which saved in firebase database but when login cannot identify the user position which saved in the firebase database so what should I do? Please anyone can give suggestion or advice me how to do this.

The database is save the uid from email authentication as the node under the root then rest details is the children of the uid.

[image]

The code like this

```
 private FirebaseAuth auth;
private EditText un, pw;
private String getun, getpw, uid;
private Button bl;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    ref = db.getReference("users").child(uid);

    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lun);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lpw);

    bl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Lbt);

    final TextView rl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lreg);

    //login
    bl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getun = un.getText().toString().trim();
            getpw = pw.getText().toString().trim();
            loginaction(getun, getpw);
        }
    });

    //open register page
    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ri = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);
            Login.this.startActivity(ri);
        }
    });
}


private void loginaction(String a, String b){

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(a, b).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("Login", "Login Success" + task.isSuccessful());

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w("Login", "Login Failed", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ref.orderByChild("position").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String ps  = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                            if(ps.equalsIgnoreCase("student")){

                                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, StudentHomePage.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }else if (ps.equalsIgnoreCase("tutor")){

                                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, TutorHomePage.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }else{

                                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                        "Wrong input. Please check again the email and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            // ...
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe have 2 child nodes from users. One for the students and for the tutors?

Comment: Can you advice me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create two child nodes from users. One for students and one for tutors.(Give both child values a value of true, otherwise firebase doesn't save the children.)

[image: Firebase tree Structure]

Have two registration buttons ..one for students and one for tutors. Registration for Tutor code.....

```
mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new 
  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(TutorsLoginActivity.this, "Sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String user_id= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tutors").child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.setValue(true);

                    }

                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Do the same for the students. Just change the `.child("Tutors")` to `.child("Students")` This will give you UIDs for the two different groups. And you can do the same when logging in. I think this is a better way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. But I changed another structure and it's work fine. Very appreciate your help. I used username to replace the uid so that the things can work smoothly which better than the uid structure.